# How can I get Xorg to handle both fglrx and intel for two devices? Getting segfault from Xorg

Tags: drivers, ati, xorg, multiple-monitors, intel-graphics

I'm trying to get a multi-monitor setup to work by utilizing my primary monitor that is connected to my AMD card and have a secondary monitor connected to my motherboard's VGA slot. The computer would bootup and have black screens for both monitors. This only happens when I specify the intel driver for the "Intel-gfx", if it's another name then nothing happens but of course the 2nd screen is black.

I'm doing this off my desktop that is running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
X.Org X Server 1.15.1
And I'm unsure what gfx driver version to put in here. I forgot which one I installed.
Mobo: GA-Z87X-D3H
Gfx card: AMD R9 290

This is my xorg.conf:

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "aticonfig Layout"
    Screen      0  "aticonfig-Screen[0]-0" 0 0
        Screen      1  "Intel-screen" LeftOf "aticonfig-Screen[0]-0"
EndSection

Section "Module"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier   "aticonfig-Monitor[0]-0"
    Option      "VendorName" "ATI Proprietary Driver"
    Option      "ModelName" "Generic Autodetecting Monitor"
    Option      "DPMS" "true"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
        Identifier   "Monitor1"
        VendorName   "Monitor Vendor"
        ModelName    "Monitor Model"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier  "aticonfig-Device[0]-0"
    Driver      "fglrx"
    BusID       "PCI:1:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Device"
        Identifier  "Intel-gfx"
        Driver      "intel"
        BusID       "PCI:0:2:0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "aticonfig-Screen[0]-0"
    Device     "aticonfig-Device[0]-0"
    Monitor    "aticonfig-Monitor[0]-0"
    DefaultDepth     24
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "Intel-screen"
    Device     "Intel-gfx"
    Monitor    "Monitor1"
    DefaultDepth     24
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

http://sprunge.us/QQij

And this other link is what I got from /var/log/Xorg.0.log

http://sprunge.us/PFXj